# How to prove $\log{n} = O(n^{0.5})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I want to prove $\log{n} = O(n^{0.5})$ but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want to prove that, for any large enough $n$, we have $\log n < \sqrt n$. There is some more sugar on top in the actual definition of $O$, but it's not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- consider the zero and sign of the derivative of $f(n)=\dfrac{\log(n)}{n^{0.5}}$